# I have server Asterisk I want display sip channel in mixmonitor

Tags: asterisk

I have 1 server Asterisk I want save sound file in folder & I can save to folder but I can't Rename file name I want when one call coming into server when called wit sip Chanel number sip saved to name file sound I want type code into context

```
[voicemenu-custom-1]
include = default
exten = s,1,NoOp(VM_Main)
exten = s,2,Answer()
exten = s,3,Set(CALLFILENAME=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-${UNIQUEID}-${CALLERID(num)})
exten = s,4,Set(CALLFILENAMES=${REPLACE(CALLFILENAME,*)})
exten = s,5,MixMonitor(${CALLFILENAMES}.wav,bW(2))
exten = s,6,Set(CDR(userfield)=audio:${CALLFILENAMES}.wav)
exten = s,7,AGI(agi://192.168.27.85/customivr)
exten = s,8,GotoIf($[${AGISTATUS} != "SUCCESS"]?ringgroup:hangup)
exten = s,9(ringgroup),Goto(ringroups-custom-1,s,1)
exten = s,10,System(/var/lib/asterisk/scripts/checkrcm.sh ${UNIQUEID}
${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)} ${CALLERID(num)})
exten = s,11(hangup),StopMixMonitor()
exten = s,12,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when call received you have DAHDI channel but you can't define sip channel until call answered by one user. lool :-> you can add dahdhi channel to your file name but you can't save sip channel. if you want this you have to rename file in hangup event